# Can I call this 32bit dll in 64bit python using interprocess comunication?

Tags: python, ctypes, 32bit-64bit

I need to call a 32 bit dll from 64 bit python and I am having trouble finding a good example using interprocess communication. I don't need to pass or return anything complicated. The dll is for corpscon which converts coordinates to different systems. Is there a best way to wrap the 32 bit dll. I looked at MSLoadlib but I am having trouble understanding how I would load my dll with MSLoadlib.

Here is the code,

```
from ctypes import *
import os

def conCoords(sysOutNum,outdatyear,outzonecode,inX,inY,inZ):
    corpslib = windll.LoadLibrary("C:\Program Files\CORPSCON6\corpscon_v6.dll")
    test00 = corpslib.corpscon_default_config()
    SetNadconPath = corpslib.SetNadconPath
    SetVertconPath = corpslib.SetVertconPath
    SetGeoidPath = corpslib.SetGeoidPath
    SetInSystem = corpslib.SetInSystem
    SetOutSystem = corpslib.SetOutSystem
    SetInDatum = corpslib.SetInDatum
    SetOutDatum = corpslib.SetOutDatum
    SetInZone = corpslib.SetInZone
    SetOutZone = corpslib.SetOutZone
    SetInUnits = corpslib.SetInUnits
    SetOutUnits = corpslib.SetOutUnits
    SetInVDatum = corpslib.SetInVDatum
    SetOutVDatum = corpslib.SetOutVDatum
    SetInVUnits = corpslib.SetInVUnits
    SetOutVUnits = corpslib.SetOutVUnits
    SetGeoidCodeBase = corpslib.SetGeoidCodeBase
    SetXIn = corpslib.SetXIn
    SetYIn = corpslib.SetYIn
    SetZIn = corpslib.SetZIn
    GetXOut = corpslib.GetXOut
    GetYOut = corpslib.GetYOut
    GetZOut = corpslib.GetZOut

    import ctypes

    SetNadconPath.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    SetNadconPath.retval = [ctypes.c_int]
    SetVertconPath.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    SetVertconPath.retval = [ctypes.c_int]
    SetGeoidPath.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
    SetGeoidPath.retval = [ctypes.c_int]
    SetInSystem.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetInSystem.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetInDatum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetInDatum.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetOutDatum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
    SetOutDatum.retval = [ctypes.c_int]
    SetOutSystem.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetOutSystem.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetInZone.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]      
    SetInZone .retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetOutZone.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]    
    SetOutZone .retval = [ctypes.c_int] 
    SetInUnits.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetInUnits .retval = [ctypes.c_int]   
    SetInVDatum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]     
    SetInVDatum .retval = [ctypes.c_int]     
    SetOutVDatum.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]    
    SetOutVDatum .retval =[ctypes.c_int]    
    SetInVUnits.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]   
    SetInVUnits .retval = [ctypes.c_int]   
    SetOutVUnits.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]    
    SetOutVUnits .retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetGeoidCodeBase.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]    
    SetGeoidCodeBase.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetXIn.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]  
    SetXIn.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetYIn.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]  
    SetYIn.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    SetZIn.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double]  
    SetZIn.retval = [ctypes.c_int]  
    GetXOut.retval =[ctypes.c_double]  
    GetYOut.retval =[ctypes.c_double]  
    GetZOut.retval = [ctypes.c_double]  

    test1 = SetNadconPath(r"C:\Program Files\CORPSCON6\Nadcon")
    test2 = SetVertconPath(r"C:\Program Files\CORPSCON6\Vertcon")
    test3 = SetGeoidPath(r"C:\Program Files\CORPSCON6\Geoid")

    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set Geographic or Stateplane
    ##
    ##################################
    sysInNum = 2 
    insys = SetInSystem(sysInNum)
    outsys = SetOutSystem(sysOutNum)

    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set Datum 83 or 27
    ##
    ##################################
    datumInYear = 1983
    indat = SetInDatum(datumInYear)
    datumOutYear = outdatyear
    outdat = SetOutDatum(datumOutYear)

    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set Zone ie 4202
    ##
    ##################################

    incode = 4202
    inzone = SetInZone(incode)

    outcode = outzonecode
    outzone = SetOutZone(outcode)

    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set Units
    ##
    ##################################

    units = 1

    outunits = SetOutUnits(units)
    inunits = SetInUnits(units)


    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set V Datum
    ##
    ##################################

    invdatum = SetInVDatum(1988)
    outvdatum = SetOutVDatum(1988)


    ###################################
    ##
    ## Set V Units
    ##
    ##################################

    invunits = SetInVUnits(1)
    outvunits = SetOutVUnits(1)

    geoidbase = SetGeoidCodeBase(2003)

    intcorpse = corpslib.corpscon_initialize_convert()

    #inX = 2790955
    #inY = 503380 
    #inZ = 2800.00

    xin = c_double(inX)
    yin = c_double(inY)
    zin = c_double(inZ)

    xout = c_double()
    yout = c_double()
    zout = c_double()

    SetXIn(xin)
    SetYIn(yin)
    SetZIn(zin)

    corpslib.corpscon_convert()

    corpslib.GetXOut.restype = c_double
    corpslib.GetYOut.restype = c_double
    corpslib.GetZOut.restype = c_double

    pntX = corpslib.GetXOut()
    pntY = corpslib.GetYOut()
    pntZ =  corpslib.GetZOut()



    return pntX,pntY,pntZ

x,y,z = conCoords(2,1983,4202,2790955,503380,2800.00)
print(x,y,z)
```

The corpscon dll can be found here.

[Corpscon.dll](http://cdm16021.contentdm.oclc.org/utils/getfile/collection/p16021coll1/id/220/filename/221.dll)

Comment: What you want to do is hard. You would have to write a Python module that (1) loads the DLL (2) provides wrappers for all of its functions and (3) responds to requests (via named pipes or COM or http or something) from another program to call those functions and return the results.

Comment: There is no way you can use 32 bit dll in 64 bit program - directly. So you need something that works as 32 bits and call it, or find 64 bits library...

Comment: Yeah that sounds difficult. I think I will look for another solution, thanks for saving me some time.

Comment: A 64-bit version of that DLL is available at: https://dhawk.github.io/corpscon_v6_64bit.dll/

Comment: Thanks David, I appreciate that. I am going to check it out this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) to create a COM server using Python 32-bit, then use the COM object in Python 64-bit.

Here's a little Chinese Pinyin converter I wrote.  It takes numbered input like `wo3 shi4 mei3guo2ren2` and converts it to `wǒ shì měiguórén`:

```
_UMLAUT_U = u'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}'

# tone number to combining diacritical table. 
_TONE = {u'1':u'\N{COMBINING MACRON}',
        u'2':u'\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}',
        u'3':u'\N{COMBINING CARON}',
        u'4':u'\N{COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}',
        u'5':u''}

class Pinyin:
    _public_methods_ = ['Convert']
    _reg_progid_ = 'PythonUtil.Pinyin'
    _reg_clsid_ = '{3A7A52BA-3162-4fc1-8182-869258D2754D}'

    @staticmethod
    def _convert(matchobj):
        """_convert(matchobj) -> replacement text
        Helper function for re.sub with three groups.
        Group 1 - one or more vowels
        Group 2 - zero or more consonants
        Group 3 - tone character '1'-'5'
        Applies pinyin tone marks to the appropriate vowel.
        Algorithm:
        In vowels, replace 'v' with umlaut-u.
        First 'a' or 'e' in vowels gets the mark,
        else first 'ou', 'o' gets the mark,
        else last vowel gets the mark.
        """
        import unicodedata
        vowels,consonants,tone = matchobj.groups()
        vowels = vowels.replace(u'v',_UMLAUT_U)
        n = vowels.lower().find(u'a')
        if n == -1:
            n = vowels.lower().find(u'e')
        if n == -1:
            n = vowels.lower().find(u'ou')
        if n != -1:
            # a, e, or ou found.
            # Add accent after the a, e, or o
            retval = vowels[:n+1] + _TONE[tone] + vowels[n+1:] + consonants
        else:
            # accent after the last vowel
            retval = vowels + _TONE[tone] + consonants
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFC',retval)

    def Convert(self,pinyin_with_tone_numbers):
        """Convert(self,pinyin_with_tone_numbers) -> pinyin_with_tone_marks
        Given a pinyin string with tone numbers, return a converted unicode
        string with tone marks.  Requires 'v' to represent umlaut-u.
        """
        import re
        # Calls conversion function for each match.
        return re.sub(
            u'''(?ix)       # ignore case, verbose
            ([aeiouv]+)     # one or more vowels (v for umlaut-u)
            ([^aeiouv]*)    # zero or more non-vowels
            ([12345])       # tone mark 1-5
            ''',self._convert,pinyin_with_tone_numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(Pinyin)
```

Run the script below to register the COM server using Python 32-bit, then in Python 64-bit use:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> s=win32com.client.Dispatch('PythonUtil.Pinyin')
>>> s.Convert('wo3 shi4 mei3guo2ren2')
'wǒ shì měiguórén'
```

Adapt as needed to your application.